# Combining two autocorrelation functions measured on same stationary process

Tags: autocorrelation

I have two autocorrelation functions measured from the same stationary process, but the two measurements were taken with different instruments that measure different lag times.  I would like to combine these two autcorrelation functions together into one single curve that spans the entire lag time of both instruments.  It seems that these could be combined in the frequency domain with Wiener-Khinchin theorem, but I have not gotten anything reasonable to come out from this.

[image: Two autocorrelation functions]

The autocorrelation data:

Short lag times:
{{0.0166638, 1.2427}, {0.0333277, 1.16926}, {0.0499915, 
  1.18007}, {0.0666553, 1.17344}, {0.0833192, 1.21829}, {0.099983, 
  1.19867}, {0.116647, 1.14627}, {0.133311, 1.17827}, {0.166638, 
  1.19614}, {0.199966, 1.19341}, {0.233294, 1.18352}, {0.266621, 
  1.18402}, {0.333277, 1.18672}, {0.399932, 1.18258}, {0.466587, 
  1.15333}, {0.533243, 1.17556}, {0.666553, 1.17179}, {0.799864, 
  1.17035}, {0.933175, 1.18451}, {1.06649, 1.16379}, {1.33311, 
  1.14078}, {1.59973, 1.13816}, {1.86635, 1.13299}, {2.13297, 
  1.13205}, {2.66621, 1.09647}, {3.19946, 1.09374}, {3.7327, 
  1.07922}, {4.26594, 1.06006}, {5.33243, 1.04623}, {6.39891, 
  1.03004}, {7.4654, 1.02369}, {8.53188, 1.01798}, {10.6649, 
  1.0145}, {12.7978, 1.00935}, {14.9308, 1.00495}, {17.0638, 
  1.00267}, {21.3297, 1.00247}, {25.5956, 1.00451}, {29.8616, 
  1.00155}, {34.1275, 1.00223}, {42.6594, 0.99827}, {51.1913, 
  1.00015}, {59.7232, 0.996647}}

Longer lag times:

{{1.483, 1.2196}, {2.966, 1.1595}, {4.4489, 1.1353}, {5.9319, 
  1.1261}, {7.4149, 1.1126}, {8.8979, 1.0907}, {10.381, 
  1.0796}, {11.864, 1.0697}, {14.83, 1.0471}, {17.796, 
  1.0397}, {20.762, 1.0229}, {23.728, 1.0199}, {29.66, 
  1.0097}, {35.592, 1.0077}, {41.524, 1.0048}, {47.455, 
  1.004}, {59.319, 1.0023}, {71.183, 1.0008}, {83.047, 
  1.0011}, {94.911, 0.99988}, {118.64, 1.0013}, {142.37, 
  1.001}, {166.09, 0.99821}, {189.82, 0.99895}, {237.28, 
  1.0015}, {284.73, 1.0006}, {332.19, 0.99739}}

Comment: what do you mean by "instruments'?

Comment: The instrument used was essentially dynamic light scattering, but using two detectors - one detector gives autocorrelation for short lag times, the other detector gives autocorrelation for long lag times.  I want to combine the autocorrelation output from both detectors.